# Push Images into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to take photos of different items or multiple photos for one item, but I am struggling to figure out how I will be able to push the images into an array.

a single image gets displayed from the first line :

```
<img ng-show="imgURI !== undefined" ng-src="{{imgURI}}" style="text-align: center">
```

but with the `ng-repeat` it doesn't display one image.

I quess my issues are:

1. what is wrong with my ng-repeat?
2. are the images actually being stored inside of the array correctly?

**HTML**

```
 <button class="button button-full button-assertive" ng-click="takePhoto()">
    Take Photo
    </button>
    <img ng-show="imgURI !== undefined" ng-src="{{imgURI}}" style="text-align: center">
<ion-item class="item item-assertive">Test array</ion-item>
 <div ng-repeat="x in array">
     <img ng-src="{{x.imgURI}}">
 </div> center">
```

**Javascript**

```
  $scope.takePhoto = function () {
              var options = {
                quality: 75,
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                allowEdit: true,
                encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                targetWidth: 300,
                targetHeight: 300,
                popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
                saveToPhotoAlbum: false
            };

                $scope.array = [];

                $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {
                    $scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
                    $scope.imgURI = array;
                }, function (err) {
                    // An error occured. Show a message to the user
                });
            }
```

Comment: what is `ar`? both in your markup (`x in ar`) and in your code (`$scope.imageUri = ar`)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to change that will edit now. @Jamiec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

test this code, i created array outside of takePhoto function and push image in it.

```
$scope.array = [];
$scope.takePhoto = function () {
    var options = {
        quality: 75,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
        allowEdit: true,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        targetWidth: 300,
        targetHeight: 300,
        popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: false
    };



    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {
        $scope.array.push("data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData);
    }, function (err) {
    // An error occured. Show a message to the user
    });
}
```

your html should be like this below

```
<div ng-repeat="x in array"> <img ng-show="x !== undefined" ng-src="{{x}}"> </div>`
```

Comment: Your coding works fine when calling a single image but as my other issue is stated I am struggling to show multiple images.  this is what I think but does not work, any Ideas? ` <div ng-repeat="x in array[0]">
     <img ng-show="x !== undefined" ng-src="{{x}}">
 </div>`

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the imageUri to the value of the array.

```
$scope.imgURI = ar;
```

I think you want to do a push on the array like this:

```
$scope.array.push($scope.imgURI);
```

Comment: Just one thing to add : since the array stores the URI as strings rather than wrapped in an object, the image in the `ng-repeat` should directly access `x` rather than `x.imgURI`

Comment: I am having issue testing it seeing that the api only works on my phone the ng-repeat does not display anything.